# Python Pandas, find index of a rolling window - is there a more efficient method?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe of TimeStamps and Bid prices. For every Bid price I want to create a rolling window of previous 1000 bid prices, find the highest value on this window and return the index of where the high was located. The index must be of the rolling window, so it'll be a number between 1 and 1000.
Here's the code I came up with, it works:

```py
df['High time'] = price_frame - ( df.index.values - df['Bid'].rolling(window=price_frame).agg(lambda x: x.index.values[np.argmax(x.values)]) )
```

As stated, it works but it's highly inefficient, takes about 15/20 seconds to compute. Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Thank's

I expect a faster code, if possibile.

#### Edit: example

I have this dataframe:

```
    Timestamp   Bid
0   2023-12-01 00:00:02.033000+00:00    1.26305
1   2023-12-01 00:00:05.974000+00:00    1.26306
2   2023-12-01 00:00:07.587000+00:00    1.26305
3   2023-12-01 00:00:07.689000+00:00    1.26306
4   2023-12-01 00:00:07.792000+00:00    1.26304
... ... ...
2383418 2024-01-04 23:59:36.774000+00:00    1.26810
2383419 2024-01-04 23:59:41.153000+00:00    1.26808
2383420 2024-01-04 23:59:41.256000+00:00    1.26808
2383421 2024-01-04 23:59:55.951000+00:00    1.26805
2383422 2024-01-04 23:59:58.573000+00:00    1.26807
```

For each row I want to create a rolling window of 1000 previous bid prices, then find the max value of that window and return the index where the high value was.
Using this code:

```
df['High time'] =  price_frame - ( df.index.values - df['Bid'].rolling(window=price_frame).agg(lambda x: x.index.values[np.argmax(x.values)]) )
```

I obtain desired result:

```
    Timestamp   Bid High time
0   2023-12-01 00:00:02.033000+00:00    1.26305 NaN
1   2023-12-01 00:00:05.974000+00:00    1.26306 NaN
2   2023-12-01 00:00:07.587000+00:00    1.26305 NaN
3   2023-12-01 00:00:07.689000+00:00    1.26306 NaN
4   2023-12-01 00:00:07.792000+00:00    1.26304 NaN
... ... ... ...
2383418 2024-01-04 23:59:36.774000+00:00    1.26810 255.0
2383419 2024-01-04 23:59:41.153000+00:00    1.26808 254.0
2383420 2024-01-04 23:59:41.256000+00:00    1.26808 253.0
2383421 2024-01-04 23:59:55.951000+00:00    1.26805 252.0
2383422 2024-01-04 23:59:58.573000+00:00    1.26807 251.0
```

The problem is that it takes up to 20 seconds. Hence I wanted to know if there's a faster way.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: `df['Bid'].rolling(window=price_frame).idxmax()`?

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I already tried, but: `'Rolling' object has no attribute 'idxmax'

Comment: maybe [rolling rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.rank.html) could be helpful? I dont know if the given example is correct tho.

Comment: @MatthiasMertens it certainly goes way faster but honestly I do not undetstand what "rank" does... Also values do not match at all with previous calculated ones.

Comment: After playing with this a little, I'm doubting it can be made to go significantly faster with standard pandas and numpy. Your solution already goes twice as fast as using .rolling() with pandas.Series.argmax(). Splitting the dataset (with overlaps) and using multiprocessing.Pool() might help. Or would a streaming solution work for you? Or maybe even (if you want to process very large batches) using Tensorflow to run it on a GPU? (which I expect would not be easy, even if it is possible)

Comment: @DavidHarris for the suggestion but this is just some time series analysis... Your solutions are way over-kill for the task I need to achieve. Anyway, if there isn't a faster way no biggie, the important thing is not missing out on potential more efficienti.

Comment: @abolish_SO That makes sense. If it does turn out you need any of those things multiprocessing.Pool() is probably by far the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a lot faster, but is a bit simpler. idxmax() returns the index of the max value. Unfortunately it doesn't work directly with rolling, which is why apply I used apply.

```
df['High time'] = df['Bid'].rolling(price_frame).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
```

Comment: I had to do: ```df['High time2'] = price_frame - ( df.index.values - df['Bid'].rolling(price_frame).apply(lambda x: x.idxmax()) )``` because otherwise it just returned the index of the whole dataframe. Anyway, this function returns the same values of mine, but it's way slower.